# Java regex, replace certain characters except if it matches a pattern

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have this string `"person","hobby","key"` and I want to remove `" "` for all words except for `key`  so the output will be `person,hobby,"key"`

```
String str = "\"person\",\"hobby\",\"key\"";
System.out.println(str+"\n");

str=str.replaceAll("/*regex*/","");

System.out.println(str); //person,hobby,"key"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```regex
\"(?!key\")(.+?)\"
```

And replace with `$1`

**Details:**

- `\"` - Match a double quotation mark character.
- `(?!key\")` - Negative Lookahead (not followed by the word "key" and another double quotation mark).
- `(.+?)` - Match one or more characters (lazy) and capture them in group 1.
- `\"` - Match another double quotation mark character.
- *Substitution:* `$1` - back reference to whatever was matched in group 1.

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jnCojC/2)**.

Here's a full example:

```java
String str = "\"person\",\"hobby\",\"key\"";
String pattern = "\"(?!key\")(.+?)\"";
String result = str.replaceAll(pattern, "$1");

System.out.println(result);  // person,hobby,"key"
```

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/OEE57928)**.

Comment: and for `key(type)` , I tried this pattern `"(?!key(.*)")(.+?)"` but didn't work I get this output `person,name,"key:VID(string), hobby"`  , how can I fix it ?

Comment: @Ziad-Mid I'm not sure I understand. If you have `"key:something"` instead of `"key"`, the quotes will be removed. Isn't that what you want? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/DnX3X7/1).

Comment: no I asked if we do the same thing but instead of key we use key(type) for example in this String `"person","name","key(string)","hobby"` I want the output as `person,name,"key(string)",hobby`

Comment: @Ziad-Mid Is it always "key(something" or do you want it to work for any string starting with "key"? Perhaps `\"(?!key)(.+?)\"` or `\"(?!key\b)(.+?)\"` is what you're after?

Comment: it is always `key(something)` I tried those you sent but they don't work it's same output as before
` person,name,"key(string), hobby" `

Comment: @Ziad-Mid Use `\"(?!key\([^\)\"]*\)\")(.+?)\"`. Or `\"(?!key(?:\([^\)\"]*\))?\")(.+?)\"` if you want to support both `"key"` and `"key(something)"`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0pGiE3/1).